# Sending activation email by gmail account - not by actual domain

Tags: php, email

I wanted to send activation link to my users. But, I restricted users to use specific email domain to register. However, I cannot send email to that domain. Maybe because that domain blocks unknown email senders like my site. So that, how can i send the activation links through my gmail account. Because gmail is allowed.(I have sent emails).

Thanks in advance.

Note:  My function mail() works fine when i changed the email address to be sent
Note2: I have to use that specific domain

Comment: I was looking at the same page but still could not understand what is Mail.php is:( Please help with it

Comment: In that case, they are using the PEAR Mail extension.  But, there are other answers for other mail classes, such as Swift Mailer.  All of them apply to you, and if you don't like any of those answers you can pick one of the other 100 duplicates.